# Django javascript Canvas late update draw

Tags: javascript, html, django, canvas

I made a form that calculates a rectangle in Django. I made a form in the html file and had it calculated with javascript and gave the data to the screen. But when I submit again by changing the data in the form, the "result" changes but the canvas is not updated. It only gets updated when I press the submit button a few times. What is the reason of this?

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="text-center">Dikdörtgen Hesaplayıcı</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form id="area-form">
                <label for="shape">Hesaplanması istenen değerleri Seçin:</label>
                <select id="shape" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="shape">
                  <option value="Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre">Alan ve Çevre</option>
                  <option value="Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk">Köşegen Uzunluk</option>
                  <option value="Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk">Kenar Uzunluk</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>

                <div id="Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre">
                  <label for="length" class="form-label" >Uzun Kenar:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" id="length" name="length">
                  <br><br>
                  <label for="width" class="form-label" >Kısa Kenar:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" id="width" name="width">
                </div>

                <div id="Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk" style="display:none;">
                  <label for="köşegen_length" class="form-label">Uzun Kenar:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" id="köşegen_length" name="köşegen_length">
                  <br><br>
                  <label for="köşegen_width" class="form-label" >Kısa Kenar:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control"step="0.0001" id="köşegen_width" name="köşegen_width">
                </div>

                <div id="Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk" style="display:none;">
                  <label for="kenar_length" class="form-label" >Kenar Uzunluk:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" id="kenar_length" name="kenar_length">
                  <br><br>
                  <label for="Köşegen" class="form-label">Köşegen Uzunluk:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" id="Köşegen" name="Köşegen">
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    

  </div></div></div></div></div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center" id="canvassonuç">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="text-center">Dikdörtgen Hesaplayıcı Sonucu</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
  <p id="result"></p>
  <canvas id="rectangle-canvas" width="900" height="300"></canvas>
  <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<br><br>
<br><br>

    {% block scripts %}
  <script src="{% static 'hesapsayfaları/alan.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Django html code

```
document.getElementById("canvassonuç").classList.add("d-none");

$('#area-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("canvassonuç").classList.add("d-none");

  var shape = $('#shape').val();
  var area_result = 0;
  var çevre_result = 0;
  var köşegen_result = 0;
  var kenar_result = 0;
  if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre') {
    var length = $('#length').val();
    var width = $('#width').val();
    area_result = length * width;
    area_result = area_result.toFixed(4);
    çevre_result = (parseFloat(length) + parseFloat(width))*2;
    document.getElementById("canvassonuç").classList.remove("d-none");
    $('#result').text('Alan: ' + area_result);
    $('#result').append('<br>Çevre: ' + çevre_result);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('rectangle-canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(50, 50, 300, 200); // (x, y, width, height)
      ctx.lineWidth = 5; // kenar kalınlığı ayarlanır
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // kenar rengi ayarlanır
      ctx.stroke(); // kenar çizilir
      ctx.font = '20px Arial'; // Yazı tipi ve boyutu
      ctx.textAlign = 'center'; // Yazının hizalaması
      ctx.fillText('Alan: ' + (length * width) + ' birim kare', 200, 150); // Yazıyı çizmek için
      ctx.fillText((length), 200, 40); // Yazıyı çizmek için
      ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2)
      ctx.fillText((width), -150, 40); // Yazıyı çizmek için
  

    }
  }
   else if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk') {
    var length = $('#köşegen_length').val();
    var width = $('#köşegen_width').val();
    köşegen_result = Math.sqrt(parseFloat(length * length)+ parseFloat(width*width));
    $('#result').text('Köşegen Uzunluğu: ' + köşegen_result);
  }
  else if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk') {
    var kenar_length = $('#kenar_length').val();
    var Köşegen = $('#Köşegen').val();
    if (kenar_length => Köşegen) {
           alert("Kenar köşegenden büyük veya eşit olamaz.");
           return false;
         }
    kenar_result = Math.sqrt(parseFloat(Köşegen * Köşegen)- parseFloat(kenar_length*kenar_length));
    $('#result').text('Diğer Kenarın Uzunluğu: ' + kenar_result);
  }
  
});

$('#shape').change(function() {
  var shape = $(this).val();
  if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre') {
    $('#Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre').show();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk').hide();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk').hide();
  } 
   else if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk') {
    $('#Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre').hide();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk').show();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk').hide();

  }
  else if (shape === 'Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk') {
    $('#Dikdörtgen_alan_çevre').hide();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_köşegen_uzunluk').hide();
    $('#Dikdörtgen_kenar_uzunluk').show();

  }
});
```

javascript code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsI2V.png)

example image

What I want is to update the data when I press the submit button only once.